# Rehaspe a 2D matrix into a 3D ? (x, y) -> (x/72,72,y)

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matrix, reshape

I have a [text file](http://pastebin.com/7hzUpFrU) from which I load the original matrix.

The text file has comments with # and it basically has multiple matrices of 77*44.

I would like to read this file and store each matrix from this complete number of mats.

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from numpy import zeros, newaxis
import io

#read the txt file and store all vaules into a np.array
f = open('/path/to/akiyo_cif.txt','r')
x = np.loadtxt(f,dtype=np.uint8,comments='#',delimiter='\t')

nof = x.shape[0]/72
print ("shape after reading the file is "+ str(x.shape) )

#example program that works
newmat =np.zeros((nof+1,72,44))
for i in range(0,nof+1):
    newmat[i,:,:]= x[i*72 : (i*72)+72 , :]
print ("Shape after resizing the file is "+ str(newmat.shape) )
```

Output :-`Shape after reading the file is (21240, 44)`

```
Shape after resizing the file is (274, 72, 44)
```

If I run this

```
newmat=x.reshape((nof,72,44))

newmat = x.reshape((nof,72,44))
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

I would like to re size this matrix to `(21240/72,72,44)`. 
Where the first 77 lines corresponds to `newmat[0,:,:]` and the next 77 lines to `newmat[1,:,:]`.

Comment: 21240 / 77 = 275,8... - there is no way it could only be 77x44 arrays. Otherwise the result would be an integer

Comment: Sorry my mistake... It's 72 not 77.. Made edits to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `x.reshape(-1, 72, 44)`:

```
In [146]: x = np.loadtxt('data' ,dtype=np.uint8, comments='#', delimiter='\t')

In [147]: x = x.reshape(-1, 72, 44)

In [148]: x.shape
Out[148]: (34, 72, 44)
```

When you specify one of the dimensions as -1, `np.reshape` replaces the -1 with a value inferred from the length of the array and the remaining dimensions.